# Does a Dockerfile's WORKDIR specify the working directory based off the host or the container?

Tags: docker

I am following the instructions on Dockerizing a node file
https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/build-images/
Following the definition from: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

> The `WORKDIR` instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile. If the `WORKDIR` doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction.

In tutorials I see `WORKDIR=/usr/src/app`.

Do I need to make `WORKDIR` the same directory as my host? E.g. `WORKDIR=/home/my-username/my-node-project`? Or does this specify an arbitrary working directory in my container?

So I could state `WORKDIR=/usr/hello-there`, and then a container would be created with a file structure including a `/usr/hello-there/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

WORKDIR

It's a directory inside your container image that can be set with the WORKDIR instruction in the Dockerfile. It is optional (default is /, but base image might have set it), but considered a good practice. Subsequent instructions in the Dockerfile, such as RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT will operate in this dir. As for COPY and ADD, they use both...